# Does the Times of the Gentiles also include the rise of Islam?

Tags: revelation, daniel, bible, gentiles

Up until the Islamic faith was founded by Mohammed in 630AD - there was only Christianity and Paganism. Bear in mind that in Biblical days and even after, there were only two groups of people - Jews and Gentiles. If you weren't a Jew, you were a Gentile. The world has gone through many phases,  the kingdom of Babylon was succeeded by that of the Medes and Persians, by the kingdom of Greece, and by the Roman Empire and then the fall of the Byzantine Empire in 1453, followed by the Ottoman Empire - an Islamic superpower run by the Turks - Sunni Islam was the official religion of the Ottoman Empire which has been one of the mightiest and long-long lasting dynasties in world history.

The four main players that made up the Umayyad Caliphate:

1. Mohammed - 570 - 632AD
2. Abu Bakr - 632 - 634
3. Umar - 634 - 644
4. Uthman (aka Osman I, a leader of the Turkish tribes) - 644 - 656

After Uthman the Islamic faith split into Shia and Sunni.

From 630 AD till today - the Islamic faith has grown with more than 2,5 billion followers!

Matthew 24:14

> And this gospel of the kingdom shall be preached in all the world for a witness unto all nations; and then shall the end come.

Not until **all the world** knows the Gospel, shall the second coming of Jesus occur, and this entire period is known as the "Times of the Gentiles".

**Other noteworthy facts about Islam.**
Over 21,000,000 Christians were persecuted mostly by Islam and it continues to this day.

2 Timothy 3:12

> Yea, and all that will live godly in Christ Jesus shall suffer persecution.

Matthew 24:11

> And many false prophets shall rise, and shall deceive many.

Muhammed certainly is one of the false prophets and Allah is a false god who has deceived billions of people.

Koran 33:40

> Mohammad is the messenger of Allah and the last of the Prophets; and Allah is ever aware of all things.

The Koran 4:157: Mohammad said Jesus did not die on the cross.

Koran 4:157

> And for their saying, "Indeed, we have killed the Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary, the messenger of Allah ." And they did not kill him, nor did they crucify him; but another was made to resemble him to them. And indeed, those who differ over it are in doubt about it. They have no knowledge of it except the following of assumption. And they did not kill him, for certain.

The Koran 3:55 and 43:57-59,63 verses quote Mohammad said Jesus did not die on the cross, but that Allah just killed him, and Jesus was not raised from the dead. Jesus awaits resurrection like everyone else.

Koran 3:55

> Then Allah said, "O Jesus, indeed I will take you and raise you to Myself and purify you from those who disbelieve and make those who follow you in submission to Allah alone superior to those who disbelieve until the Day of Resurrection. Then to Me is your return, and I will judge
> between you concerning that in which you used to differ.

Koran 43:57-59

> And when the son of Mary was presented as an example, immediately your people laughed aloud. And they said, "Are our gods better, or is he?" They did not present the comparison except for mere argument. But, in fact, they are a people prone to dispute. Jesus was not but a servant upon whom We bestowed favor, and We made him an example for the Children of Israel.

Koran 43:63

> And when Jesus brought clear proofs, he said, "I have come to you with wisdom and to make clear to you some of that over which you differ, so fear Allah and obey me.

Revelation 13 tells us of two beasts - one from the sea and one from the earth.

Revelation 13:11

> And I beheld another beast coming up out of the earth; and he had two horns like a lamb, and he spake as a dragon.

Muslims consistently say Jesus promised Mohammad would follow him, and cite John 16:13 ("The Spirit of Truth") as proof. Of course, Jesus was talking about the Holy Spirit, not a person. That Jesus promised Muhammad is a common teaching in Islam. Therefore Revelation 13:11 warns us that the
False Prophet will attempt to look like the Lamb, be connected to, or be associated with the Lamb.

Today all of Islam fights for the Outer Court on the Temple Mount. The Koran says Mohammad was taken to the outer court on the Temple Mount on a white horse, a place Revelation 11:2 says was set aside for non-believing gentiles, and does not belong to the people of God since it is "excluded."
Al-Aqsa Dome of the Rock mosque in Jerusalem was completed in 705AD and is situated in the outer court.

Revelation 11:2

> But the court which is without the temple leave out, and measure it not; for it is given unto the Gentiles: and the holy city shall they tread under foot forty [and] two months.

Koran 17:1

> Holy is He Who carried His servant [Mohammad] by night from the Holy Mosque in Mecca to the farther Mosque in Jerusalem - whose surroundings we have blessed - that we might show him some of our signs.

To understand the spiritual importance of the image and the mark, we must understand they are an abomination to the true God, and yet most important to those that worship a false god. In other words they are important to both Christ and the antichrist. The Islamic Shahada (the mark) and daily
prayer and pilgrimage to the Kaaba (the image) are key worship parts of the Five Pillars of Islam. The final form of the Shahada was completed in the year 666. His image is the **Kaaba Black Stone** set up by Mohammad in Mecca,

Revelation 2:17

> He that hath an ear, let him hear what the Spirit saith unto the churches; To him that overcometh will I give to eat of the hidden manna, and will give him a **white stone**, and in the stone a new name written, which no man knoweth saving he that receiveth it.

Considering these facts I am of the belief that we are still in the Times of the Gentiles and furthermore believe that people should stop just looking towards Western civilizations and religions and start recognizing the dangers of Islam. There are currently over 351 warnings in the Bible against Islam.

Mohammed is also a direct descendant of Ishmael, the firstborn son of Abraham. So what do know about Ishmael?

Genesis 16:12

> And he will be a wild man; his hand will be against every man, and every man's hand against him; and he shall dwell in the presence of all his brethren.

Genesis 21:20

> And God was with the lad; and he grew, and dwelt in the wilderness, **and became an archer.**

Mohammed is the first Horseman

Revelation 6:2

> And I saw, and behold a **white horse**: and he that sat on him had a **bow**; and a crown was given unto him: and he went forth conquering, and to conquer.

Abu Bakr is the second Horseman

Genesis 6:4

> And there went out another horse [that was] **red:"" and [power] was given to him that sat thereon to take peace from the earth, and that they should kill one another: and there was given unto him a great sword.

He crushed the rebellion of the Arab tribes throughout the Arabian Peninsula in the successful Ridda Wars. Though the period of his caliphate covered only 27 months, it included successful invasions of the two most powerful empires of the time: the Sassanid Persian Empire and Byzantine Eastern Roman Empire.

Umar is the third Horsemen

Revelation 6:5

> And when he had opened the third seal, I heard the third beast say, Come and see. And I beheld, and lo a **black horse**; and he that sat on him had a pair of balances in his hand.

Revelation 6:6

> And I heard a voice in the midst of the four beasts say, A measure of wheat for a penny, and three measures of barley for a penny; and [see] thou hurt not the oil and the wine.

Among the many things Umar did was impose a new tax system.  Umar - "The King will do as he pleases" in Daniel 11:36-45. Daniel was taken captive in 605 BC as part of the Babylonian captivity of Israel. Daniel finished his work around the year 530 BC, shortly after the capture of Babylon by Cyrus of Persia in 539 BC. In the book of Daniel (Daniel 11:36-45 and 7:23-25) he sees a future king who treats the Holy People very badly. This King defeats three kings and changes the set times and laws. In all, Umar fulfilled 31 prophecies of Daniel. This king has many battlefield conquests and invades the Holy Land. Today many people think this king is still in the future (perhaps the “Antichrist”), but almost certainly Daniel was writing about the second Muslim caliph after Mohammad named Umar. Daniel wrote this 1,200 years before Umar. Umar was murdered in a mosque in Media, and no one came to help him.

Uthman is the fourth Horsemen. Revelation tells us the fourth rider is on a **pale green horse**

Revelation 6:8

> And I looked, and behold a pale horse: and his name that sat on him was Death, and Hell followed with him. And power was given unto them over the fourth part of the earth, to kill with sword, and with hunger, and with death, and with the beasts of the earth.

Uthman is critically important in Islamic history because after his death marked the beginning of open massive religious and civil war conflicts within the Islamic community (called the “Fitnah”). Uthman was also murdered by other Muslims. Following his death, Ali was chosen as the fourth caliph, but not before violent conflict broke out. War erupted when Ali became caliph, and he too was killed in fighting in the year 661 near the town of Kufa, now in present-day Iraq.

Revelation tells us the Four Horsemen will have power over one-quarter of the world. (Revelation 6:8 "They were given power over a fourth of the earth to kill by sword, famine and plague, and by the wild beasts of the earth.") The Four Horsemen set in motion the Umayyad Caliphate.

At its greatest extent, the Umayyad Caliphate (661-750) covered 15 million square kilometers (5.8 million square miles) and had power over 62 million people (estimated between 25% to 29% of the world’s population at that time), making it the one of the largest empires in history in both area and
proportion of the world’s population. Today about 28% of the world is Islamic. The "Rightly Guided Caliphs" is a term used in Sunni Islam to refer to the 30-year reign of the first four caliphs (successors) following the death of the Islamic prophet Mohammad, namely: Abu Bakr, Umar, Uthman, and Ali.

The Bible says the colors of the Four Horsemen are 1) white, 2) red and 3) black, these colors are the colors of Islam.  Many translations give the fourth color as "pale". The correct translation is green, or pale green. The Greek word in Revelation 6:8 for the fourth color is chlóros: or pale green.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX. Thanks for your question. Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Is this a sermon or a question?  It reads more like a statement of faith.  This is confirmed by the fact that you never quote Luke 21:24 where the phrase "Times of the Gentiles" comes from.

Comment: If this sounds like a statement of faith, then you dont know what a statement of faith is.

Comment: Luke 21:24 And they shall fall by the edge of the sword, and shall be led away captive into all nations: and Jerusalem shall be trodden down of the Gentiles, until the times of the Gentiles be fulfilled.

Comment: There is a question in the Title, but the overly long Body doesn't contain any question at all. It is simply an answer, but even then, it's not obvious that it is answering the Title question. It's okay to answer one's own question here, but that answer should be a separate posting. ¶ As for the actual question, the Body should start with a scriptural quotation and then ask about it (in this case about its meaning). The Body should be relatively brief, and not contain any opinions or answers.

Comment: I asked a question and provided my understanding, if someone is not in agreement, then please provide a better answer to the one I proposed.

Comment: Maybe you should mention and contextualize the “Hanif” religion. In Koran Abraham is said to be a (righteous) follower of this religion.

Comment: Another thing to add some context to the statement about “sermon”.  it may be better to only post the actual question as the question on this site and put the hypothetical answer as a self-answer separately. This will make it easier to appreciate and upvote your question for the people who don’t support your hypothesis.

Comment: The statement simplifies the historical religious landscape by implying there were only Christians and Pagans before Islam. This overlooks other religions such as Zoroastrianism, Hinduism, Buddhism, and various indigenous faiths that were prevalent in different parts of the world. Some also state that Jesus is someone who’s teaching resembles the one from Buddha Amitabha.

Comment: **Context** The "times of the Gentiles" has nothing to do with Islam, Britain, Ottomans, etc. The context deals with the Fall of Jerusalem to the Romans in 70 A.D. This was prophesied about by Jesus in Matthew 22-24...and in Daniel, where the exact length of the destruction was given by the Angels!  An amazing prophecy that gave 1330 days as the "Time." (Or "time, times, and part of a time"  Chapter 12)  Jesus also told the woman at the well that Jerusalem was no longer to be a focal point of worship, ever again (John 4).  Spiritual worship is at the heart of God, not a place.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a matter of opinion. Although the question may therefore be closed as "opinion-based" it would be a shame for the good work the author put in to go to waste. My answer:

- If one believes that the Book of Revelation has yet to be fulfilled, then the so-called Times of the Gentiles includes the rise of Islam. The OP presents one plausible scenario for this.
- If one believes that Revelation was already fulfilled shortly after it was written or that it will never be literally fulfilled because it is largely symbolic,  the Times of the Gentiles does not include the rise of Islam.
- A third possibility is that the Book of Revelation includes the rise of Islam but does not refer to it in the precise way that the OP does.

Answer (score 0):

When many people read "the times of the gentiles," they usually "auto-correct" it in their minds to, "the time of the gentiles," which misses the point. What the times of the gentiles is actually referring to are the 3.5 years in Daniel's prophecy:

> [Dan 7:25 NASB95] [25] 'He will speak out against the Most High and wear down the saints of the Highest One, and he will intend to make alterations in times and in law; **and they will be given into his hand for a time, times, and half a time.**

> [Luk 21:20-24 NASB95] [20] "But when you see **Jerusalem surrounded by armies**, then recognize that **her desolation is near**. [21] "Then those **who are in Judea must flee to the mountains, and those who are in the midst of the city must leave, and those who are in the country must not enter the city; [22] because these are days of vengeance, so that all things which are written will be fulfilled.** [23] "Woe to those who are pregnant and to those who are nursing babies in those days; **for there will be great distress upon the land and wrath to this people; [24] and they will fall by the edge of the sword, and will be led captive into all the nations; and Jerusalem will be trampled under foot by the Gentiles until the times of the Gentiles are fulfilled.**

The "shattering of the People" (IE: the Jews) refers to the destruction of the 2nd Temple, the Sanhedrin, the Sinai Covenant and the relevance of the Torah to justification, by the armies of Titus of Rome and his mercenaries. The war lasted 3.5 years.

> [Dan 12:7 NASB95] [7] I heard the man dressed in linen, who was above the waters of the river, as he raised his right hand and his left toward heaven, **and swore by Him who lives forever that it would be for a time, times, and half [a] [time;] and as soon as they finish shattering the power of the holy people, all these [events] will be completed.**

The 1,260 days refers to the same thing. The Jewish years were reckoned as 360 days, because they had a lunar calendar, and so the years weren't always the same length. So 360 is one year, rounded. 1260/360=3.5:

> [Rev 11:3 NASB95] [3] "And I will grant [authority] to my two witnesses, and they will prophesy for **twelve hundred and sixty days**, clothed in sackcloth."

> [Rev 12:6 NASB95] [6] Then the woman fled into the wilderness where she had a place prepared by God, so that there she would be nourished for **one thousand two hundred and sixty days**.

Any interpretation of Daniel, Matthew 24, Luke 21, Revelation etc. that does not refer to the first century exclusively is deep in the weeds.